# How can I fetch object from ForeignKey with date after now in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have the following models:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Morada")
    nif = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], unique=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

class Flight(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name="Data")
    flight_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Ref. Voo")
    company = models.ForeignKey(AirCompany, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Companhia")
    airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Aeroporto")

class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Ref. Viagem", primary_key=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='Destino')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Cliente")
    out_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, related_name="outbound_flight" ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Ida")
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Hotel")
    in_flight = models.ForeignKey (Flight, related_name="inbound_flight", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Regresso")
```

Knowing that both `Flight` and `Clients` are a ForeignKey in `Trip`, how can I fetch all the clients who have flights after now?

I used `Going = Flight.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('date')` to get all the flights leaving after now, but I also need to get which clients are going after now.

Comment: @MehaParekh But `Flight` doesn't seem to have any relation to `Clients` directly..

Comment: ya, sorry my mistake but you can get it through the trip object

Comment: @MehaParekh they all have relations on the `Trip` model. Is this possible, or should they have explicitly relations in each model?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa no need to have explicitly relations in each model you can use `Trip` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this,

```
from django.utils import timezone

Clients.objects.filter(trip__out_flight__date__gt=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Eventhough I have clients with flights leaving in two weeks, the queryset returns empty.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice I was only getting the `out_flight`. Is it possible to also get the `in_flight` on the same query?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa yes, it is possible for `in_flight` just need to change `trip__out_flight__date__gt` to `trip__in_flight__date__gt` and you can use less than also using lt instead of gt

Comment: @MehaParekh that I tested and could do, but can I fetch both (in and out)?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa yes you can do that with Q objects. Doc Link: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects`

Comment: @JoãodeSousa Q objects are used for ORing operations if you want Anding with those two you can simply write query using `,` operator.

Comment: @MehaParekh i tried using `,`, but even looping on the template, I get the queryset instead of each item.

Comment: you can iterate over queryset and access fields using `.` operator